# Does Protractor tool support Windows desktop application for UI automation?

Tags: protractor, desktop-application, ui-automation

We have Web Application which interacts with Windows base desktop applications.Can Protractor be used to automate UI workflows for desktop application as well?

Answer (score 2):

Protractor is nothing but a framework built on top of `webdriver js` to automate angular js web applications.It uses API's available in selenium jar file to communicate with the browser. Selenium doesn't have support to automate desktop applictions,hence protractor also cannot be used to automate desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use RobotJs code within Protractor to control